# delegate with confirm and unsubscribe issue

Tags: c#, events, delegates, unsubscribe

I am struggling with the delegate/event. Most likely I do not understand the whole picture.
for the sake of argument, I have two forms: form 1 and form 2.

Questions:

1. How to appropriately unsubscribe the event "frm2.ButtonClicked -= new PassMsg(MsgReceivedFromFrm2);"?
2. If I kill form 2, I still get the confirming message.why does this happenning?

:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    PassMsg NotifyFrm2EventHandler;                             // Delegate definition
    PassMsgWithConfirm NotifyFrm2WithConfirmEventHandler;       // Delegate with return definition
    event PassMsg NotifyFrm2AsEvent;                            // Event definition
    int i;
   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        i = 0;
    }

    private void btn_InitializeFrm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        NotifyFrm2EventHandler = new PassMsg(frm2.ReceiveMsgFromForm1);                                             // setup link from Form 1 to Form 2
        NotifyFrm2WithConfirmEventHandler = new PassMsgWithConfirm(frm2.ReceiveMsgFromForm1withConfirm);            // setup link from Form 1 to Form 2
        NotifyFrm2AsEvent += new PassMsg(frm2.ReceiveMsgFromForm1);                                                 // setup link from Form 1 to Form 2
        frm2.ButtonClicked += new PassMsg(MsgReceivedFromFrm2);                                                     // setup link from Form 2 to Form 1
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void btn_Send2Frm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;

        NotifyFrm2EventHandler?.Invoke("message from form 1 with index " + i.ToString());                                    //  Notification by Call
    }

    private void btn_Send2Frm2WithConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        bool confirmed = (bool)(NotifyFrm2WithConfirmEventHandler?.Invoke("message from form 1 with confirm with index" + i.ToString()));             //  Notification by Call
        if (confirmed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("confirmed.");
        }

    }

    private void btn_sendAsEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        NotifyFrm2AsEvent?.Invoke("message from form 1 as event with index" + i.ToString());                                //  Notification by Call
    }


    void MsgReceivedFromFrm2(string input)
    {
        label1.Text = input;
    }

}
```

And form2 code:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public event PassMsg ButtonClicked;             // Event definition

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ReceiveMsgFromForm1(string input)
    {
        label1.Text = input;
    }

    public bool ReceiveMsgFromForm1withConfirm(string input)
    {
        label1.Text = input;
        return true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonClicked("Message from Form 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always the class (a form in this case) which raises an event (Invoke), that defines the event. Invoking, firing or raising an event is like broadcasting a message. This class is called the publisher. The event is therefore `public` in most cases.

The other class attaching to this event with `+=` is the subscriber. It is the receiver of this message.

You somehow mixed up publisher and subscriber.

An event is like an auto property but for a delegate. So,

```cs
public event MessageEventHandler Message;
```

defines an event `Message`. It is equivalent to

```cs
private MessageEventHandler _messageEventHandler;
public event MessageEventHandler Message
{
   add 
   { 
       _messageEventHandler += value;
   } 
   remove 
   { 
      _messageEventHandler -= value;
   }
}
```

So, you don't need these explicit event handler field declarations. Also, it is not necessary to create the delegates explicitly with `new`. `+= EventHandlerMethod` alone is just fine.

---

If you want `Form2` to handle an event from `Form1`, it would be better to pass `Form1` as a constructor parameter to `Form2`. The event handler in `Form2` then can be private. It is also up to `Form2` to subscribe to the event or not. Controls are defining many events, but your form as receiver subscribes to only a few of them if any.

Sender side:

```cs
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public delegate void MessageEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event MessageEventHandler Message;

    ... constructor and other stuff not shown here.

    private void btnInitializeFrm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You don't care who is receiver. You might have many receivers or none.
        OnMessage($"Message from form 1 with index {i}");
    }

    private virtual void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        Message?.Invoke(new MessageEventArgs { Message = message });
    }
}
```

Subscriber:

```cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form1 = form1;
        form1.Message += Form1_Message;
    }

    private void Form1_Message(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 got message: " + e.Message);
    }

    private void btnUnsubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.Message -= Form1_Message;
    }
}
```

See also

- [Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)
- [Standard .NET event patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern)

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will do. thanks again